# Input type number is blank, but stored 0 as default

Tags: reactjs, input, material-ui, formik

The initial value is blank, but when I `POST` the form it is as default value **0** and **not null**

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      previous_experience: "",
     }})
```

This is the input field:

```
<TextField
                  fullWidth
                  label="Previous Experience Required"
                  name="previous_experience"
                  variant="outlined"
                  type="number"
                  value={formik.values.previous_experience}
                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  error={
                    formik.touched.previous_experience &&
                    Boolean(formik.errors.previous_experience)
                  }
                  helperText={
                    formik.touched.previous_experience &&
                    formik.errors.previous_experience
                  }
                />
```

How to store as a default value `NULL` and not `ZERO`?

Comment: This is not the default html / js behaviour of a number input. Probably your TextField Component does this change in behaviour? If you set value null to input type="number" the resulting value on submit should be an empty string ("").

Comment: @NickG This is from MUI Library so consider that as a default <input type=number />
How to restrict of being 0 by default